# User-friendly way to display a Visual in a WPF application?

Tags: wpf, user-interface

Looking for a simple, elegant way to display any given Visual to the user.  The only way I can think of off my head is to slap it in a brush and paint it on a Rectangle that's in a ScrollViewer.  Not exactly the best option.

Comment: What's the need for such the low-level tie in?

Comment: This seems like one of those questions that would benefit from a higher level description of what you really need so that we can give you alternatives.

Comment: @Aaron @Tergiver No alternatives are possible.  I combine visuals to create XpsDocuments.  I know them as Visuals, although they may be anything that extends from Visual.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My (current) answer is to slap it in an XpsDocument and display it in a DocumentViewer.  I could, I suppose, do it a little less complex, but I already have the infrastructure to do it this way.  Its not 100%, but it works.

First, a behavior so that I can bind to DocumentViewer.Document (its a friggen POCO, urgh):

```
public sealed class XpsDocumentBinding
{
    #region Document
    /// <summary>
    /// The <see cref="DependencyProperty"/> for <see cref="Document"/>.
    /// </summary>
    public static readonly DependencyProperty DocumentProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
            "Document",
            typeof(XpsDocument), //
            typeof(XpsDocumentBinding),
            new UIPropertyMetadata(null, OnDocumentChanged));

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the value of the <see cref="DocumentProperty">Document attached property</see> on the given <paramref name="target"/>.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="target">The <see cref="DependencyObject">target</see> on which the property is set.</param>
    public static XpsDocument GetDocument(DependencyObject target)
    {
        return (XpsDocument)target.GetValue(DocumentProperty);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Sets the <paramref name="value"/> of the <see cref="DocumentProperty">Document attached property</see> on the given <paramref name="target"/>.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="dependencyObject">The <see cref="DependencyObject">target</see> on which the property is to be set.</param>
    /// <param name="value">The value to set.</param>
    public static void SetDocument(DependencyObject target, XpsDocument value)
    {
        target.SetValue(DocumentProperty, value);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Called when Document changes.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender">The sender.</param>
    /// <param name="e">The <see cref="System.Windows.DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs"/> instance containing the event data.</param>
    private static void OnDocumentChanged(object sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var viewer = sender as DocumentViewer;
        if (viewer == null)
            throw new InvalidOperationException(
              "This behavior is only valid on DocumetViewers.");
        var doc = e.NewValue as XpsDocument;
        if (doc == null)
            return;
        viewer.Document = doc.GetFixedDocumentSequence();
    }
    #endregion
}
```

Then in my model I expose my visual as an XpsDocument

```
var pack = PackageStore.GetPackage(_uri);
if (pack != null)
    return new XpsDocument(pack, CompressionOption.SuperFast, _uri.AbsoluteUri);

MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(2048);
Package p = Package.Open(ms, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.ReadWrite);
PackageStore.AddPackage(_uri, p);
XpsDocument doc = new XpsDocument(p, CompressionOption.SuperFast, _uri.AbsoluteUri);

var writer = XpsDocument.CreateXpsDocumentWriter(doc);
var collator = writer.CreateVisualsCollator();
// write the visuals using our collator
collator.BeginBatchWrite();
collator.Write(Visual);
collator.EndBatchWrite();
p.Flush();
return doc;
```

Just add a DocumentViewer, bind the result of the conversion method to it via the behavior, and there it is.  I'm sure there's a shortcut in here somewhere...

Answer (score 2):

You could create a wrapper that inherits from `FrameworkElement` that would either host your `Visual` or a generic wrapper that will host any object deriving from `Visual`.

Take a look at the example in [Visual.AddVisual](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.visual.addvisualchild.aspx) or, if you want to host more than one visual, take a look at the (partial) example in [Using DrawingVisual Objects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742254.aspx)

Comment: Well, if I have a visual and put it in another visual, I'm not much farther down the line.  I was playing with the DrawingVisual and possibly putting that in an Image, but it was like I was going down the rabbit hole...  How could I get to either one of these to a user experience where a user could easily zoom and pan around the Visual?

Comment: Although the link points to Visual.AddVisual, if you look at the example you need to host the `Visual` in a `FrameworkElement` - there is no need to put it inside a `DrawingVisual`. Sorry about the confusion.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see a way how you could do that since a Visual has neither a position nor a size. Perhaps stick to FrameworkElement and create a style for it?

Comment: Well, the size and position can be determined by what it is in.  Which is what I'm looking for.  What I can put it in.